# How do I update info in a class when I edit the jTable linked to it?

Tags: java, class, netbeans, jtable

I'm working on an app which has a database class consisting of employee objects. The employees are represented as rows in a jTable. If you double-click on a row, a dialog with employee info pops up. This info has been stored in the employee class. The problem is that when I edit the employee info in the jTable manually, the info in the class doesn't get updated. So if I double click an employee, the old info shows and not the edited info. How do I adapt the info in the class, if I edit the jTable manually?

Sorry if this isn't clear, I'm still new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295612/how-do-i-update-info-in-a-class-when-i-edit-the-jtable-linked-to-it) might help you.

Comment: Add `KeyReleased Event` to your `jTable ` and update the employee info after user pressed the enter button.

Comment: Fishstick, you linked to this question haha. Could you re-link to the question? 

Chalitha, do you have example code for how to set up the KeyReleased Event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the `jTable` cell will not update the employee data because `jTable` is only displaying your employee details. So what you can do is, create a `KeyReleased Event` to your `jTable` and update the employee details in your database.

In netbeans you can simply create a `KeyReleased Event` by right clicking on your `jTable` and in the popup menu go to `Events`-> `Key`->`KeyReleased`.

Netbeans will automatically creates a code like this:

```
 private void yourTableNameKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

}
```

Then wirte your code in that `yourTableNameKeyReleased` method to update your employee details.

```
if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){

    int RowInView = YourTableName.getSelectedRow();

    if(RowInView >= 0){
    int RowInTableModel = YourTableName.convertRowIndexToModel(RowInView);

    String TextOnColumn1 = (YourTableName.getModel().getValueAt(RowInTableModel, 0).toString());
    String TextOnColumn2 = (YourTableName.getModel().getValueAt(RowInTableModel, 1).toString());
    String TextOnColumn3 = (YourTableName.getModel().getValueAt(RowInTableModel, 2).toString());

   // Write the code to update the employees details using these string values.
    }
}
```